# Best practice for storing dynamic data

Tags: mysql

I have a table "House" with 25 columns like: 
-kitchen,
-pool,
-garden,
- ...

Each of these columns can store multiple descriptions (or in some cases single). What is the best practice to store it? Should I create a table "HoseColumnDetail" with type ("KitchenDetail", "PoolDetail", ...) and value in order to story multiple descriptions or  save it as a hash in the "House" table ?

Answer (score 1):

How are you going to use this data? If you store in the DB only for storage, and you don't query on these specific details (e.g. - you don't index them), it might be that a good practice it to store all this data as text field, maybe as json document.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a houseDescriptions table having 3 columns.

1. ID (a foreign key to your House Table)
2. Description category (like garden, porch, etc...)
3. Description (the text)

Let's say you have house 1, it has two garden descriptions. The table would look like this.

- 1,garden,description text 1
- 1,garden,description text 2

Getting all of the garden descriptions for a house could be fetched with the following query:

```
SELECT house.somecol, house.somecol, houseDescriptions.description FROM house INNER JOIN houseDescriptions WHERE houseDescriptions.descriptionCategory = "garden";
```